# remove a tab item in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have a code as follows

```
var tabs1 = new Ext.TabPanel('tabs2');
idHistoryReportsTabItem = tabs1.addTab('script1', idHistoryReportsTabCaption);
seatHistoryReportsTabItem = tabs1.addTab('markup1', seatHistoryReportsTabCaption);
tabs1.activate("script1");
```

i want to remove tab item markup1 from the tabs2, how do i do?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no addTab function in Tabpanel: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.TabPanel  You can use the "add" and "remove" functions to achieve this:

```
Ext.getCmp('tabs2').remove('markup1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tabs1.getItem('markup1').remove();
```

Comment: This shouldn't be the answer to a question, it's more deserving of a comment.